# Separating mouse down and mouse click events

Tags: c#, winforms, drag

I have two events wired to a control. A mouse click event plays an audio file. A drag event made up from mouse down, mouse move and mouse up drags the control vertically.  By dragging the control vertically the control get assigned a different song.
The problem I have is that when I drag the control the music plays. I do not want this since this is a dragging operation.
Music should play only when control is clicked and note moved.
I think that setting boundaries, e.g. when control moves only 5 pixels play sound otherwise drag control should solve the problem but I tried to create them unsuccessfully.

Can you please guide how to solve this problem preferably with code snippets.
Thank You.
The Drag

```
   int Locked_yLoc; int index;
   private void StartDrag(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
       {
           sp1.SoundLocation = this.pitch + ".wav";
           sp1.Play();
           tm1.Interval = 100 * this.noteDuration;
           tm1.Start();

           isDragging = true;
           pitch = e.Y;
           this.Location = new Point(this.Location.X, pitch);
       }
   }

   private void StopDrag(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
       {
           isDragging = false;
           this.Location = new Point(this.Location.X, Locked_yLoc);
           pitch = index;
           //lbl8.Text = pitch.ToString();
       }
   }

   private void OnDrag(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       if (isDragging)
       {
           this.Top = this.Top + (e.Y - pitch);

           Locked_yLoc = (int)Math.Round((this.Top + (e.Y - pitch)) / 10.0) * 10;
           for (int i = 0; i < yLocation.Length; i++)
           {
               if (Locked_yLoc == yLocation[i])
               {
                   index = CorrPitch[i];
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

The Click

```
   private void MusicNote_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
       {
           sp1.SoundLocation = this.pitch + ".wav";
           sp1.Play();
           tm1.Interval = 100 * this.noteDuration;
           tm1.Start();

       }
   }
```

Comment: Why don't you simply extend your condition for in _MouseClick:  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && !isDragging)?

Comment: I have tried this but it is not working.

Comment: Sigh, these musical note questions are getting old, looks like your entire class is asking for help.  Can't y'all just work together on it?  Just use a bool field, name it "JustDragged".  Set it to true when you drag, ignore the Click event when it is set.  Set it false with MouseDown.

Comment: It *seems* not to be working since you play your wav twice: once in _MouseClick and once in StartDrag.